# Facebook Multiple Images upload

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to upload multiple images from my Application .

I would have array of images and i am using this code to upload all images . But while uploading my UI gets blocked if images are more . So Please suggest me How to start uploading in background or suggest me an alternate way ..

```
 HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.labelText = @"Uploading Images";
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
[HUD show:YES];

NSMutableArray *aryFetchedImages = [self fetchPhotosForAlbum];

for (int i = 0; i < aryFetchedImages.count ; i++) {
    NSLog(@"img%d",i);
    [params setObject:@" " forKey:@"message"];
    [params setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([aryFetchedImages objectAtIndex:i], 50.0f)  forKey:@"picture"];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             //showing an alert for failure
            #ifdef DEBUG
                NSLog(@"Unable to share the photo please try later - Fail %@",error);
            #endif
         }
         else
         {
             //showing an alert for success
            #ifdef DEBUG
                NSLog(@"Photo %@ uploaded on Facebook Successfully",UIImageJPEGRepresentation([aryFetchedImages objectAtIndex:i], 50.0f));
            #endif
         }
     }];
}
[HUD show:NO];
[HUD removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing some modification in code please try this, and let me know

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.labelText = @"Uploading Images";
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    [HUD show:YES];

    NSMutableArray *aryFetchedImages = [self fetchPhotosForAlbum];

    for (int i = 0; i < aryFetchedImages.count ; i++) {

    [self postImgWithMessage:[aryFetchedImages objectAtIndex:i];
    }


    [HUD show:NO];
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];


    //my code to be added

    -(void)postImgWithMessage:(UIImage *)image 
    {
        NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *filePath =[[paths1 objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];    
        if (filePath == nil) return;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request addFile:filePath forKey:@"file"];
        [request setPostValue:[userDefaults stringForKey:KToken] forKey:@"access_token"];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendToPhotosFinished:)];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startAsynchronous];

    }

    - (void)sendToPhotosFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
        //NSLog(@"photo sent");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch queues let you execute arbitrary blocks of code either asynchronously or synchronously with respect to the caller. You can use dispatch queues to perform nearly all of the tasks that you used to perform on separate threads. The advantage of dispatch queues is that they are simpler to use and much more efficient at executing those tasks than the corresponding threaded code.[Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24)